# I want to add a site in IIS 10 programmatically by c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, iis-10

I want to add site in IIS 10 by c#.net on windows 10

Site Added but site not shown in IIS, when I loop sites by code, My added sites come into loop but not shown in IIS. Site already manually added also not appear in IIS.

```cs
if (server.Sites != null && server.Sites.Count > 0)
{

    if (server.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "MySite") == null)
    {

        string path = @"D:\ePrintLatestVersion\ePrint\";


        string ip = "*";
        string port = "80";
        string hostName = "*";

        string bindingInfo = string.Format(@"{0}:{1}:{2}", ip, port, hostName);
        Site site = server.Sites.Add("MySite", "http", bindingInfo, path);
        site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = "Test123";
        server.CommitChanges();
        site.Start();
    }
}
```

No exception appears. As a result this code site "MySite" should appear in IIS, but it does not appear.

Comment: _"Site already manually added also not appear in IIS"_ - interesting

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. Sites added manually in IIS appear in IIS, but not appear when I loop to view all sites by this code foreach (Site site in server.Sites)
            {
                a+= site.Name + "\n";
            }

Comment: You sure `server` is pointing at the right server?

Comment: Yes, I am trying on local host. And in the above block of code, a line was missing from top. That is  ServerManager server = new ServerManager(); And Added a referece to Microsoft.Web.Administration

Comment: It is well known that if you use the wrong reference, your changes go to IIS Express, not full IIS, https://blog.lextudio.com/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know-b82f2c974da6

Comment: can some one guide please ?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to you run the codes? in a console application? I have created a test demo on my side and run with administrator permission it works well.

Comment: I call this code on Page load event of a web form. Its a web application.

Comment: I have tried your codes in asp.net webform page load event and it works well.Could you please post more details codes about your page load event?

Comment: Thanks brother. I will let you know.